# how to create a fullscreen overlay menu?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a full-screen menu with two sides, one side has a list of items; Home, Services, Portfolio and the other side will show an image on item hover. For example, if mouse hover on Services, a new image shows up and so.

This is what I need:
[image]

But, this is what I have so far:
[image]

Another example of what I'm trying to do is [this website](https://avexdesigns.com/our-work/)

Any help pleaseee??

Thanks,

PS: Hide the image in mobile.

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $dkgreen;
  background-color: $dkgreen;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  /*    top: 25%;*/
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  * margin-top: 30px;
  */
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class=" navbar navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./img/maduro-logo.png" class="img-fluid" width="115" /></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" onclick="openNav()">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">

      <div class="row overlay-content">

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; 
    </a>
        <div class="col-sm-5">

          <a style="color: #fff;" id="" class="" href="index.php">Home</a>
          <a style="color: #fff;" id="" class="" href="services.php">Services</a>
          <a style="color: #fff;" id="" class="" href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
          <a style="color: #fff;" id="" class="" href="clients.php">Clients</a>
          <a style="color: #fff;" id="" class="" href="contact.php">Contact</a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/a.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: Do you want this to happen in mobile or both in pc and mobile

Comment: Only in Desktop ... In mobile ...I would like to have 6 squares in 2 columns (3 in each side) with icons representing the item name...but that will be another question

Comment: I got your point. Give me sometime, I'll come with the code

Comment: Awesome!! .... And please let me know what size the images have to be!..coz i think that was my issue too

Comment: I will set it for all sizes of images.Is it ok if I come with my own html structure or do you want me to follow you code and come with a solution

Comment: As long as it works lol..Im fine... I am using bootstrap ..but that's ok...I will add another picture so you can see how my menu button looks like

Comment: There you go....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177824/discussion-between-jmaster-b-and-ramesh).

Comment: All you need are openNav() and closeNav() functions. To now write everything here, I would recommend you to check out the this [tutorial](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-create-fullscreen-overlay-navigation-menu.html). It describes how to act step-by-step.

Comment: @NancyBrown Love it!...Thanks, I will try it next time...I created this menu almost 2 year ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#home').hover(function() {
  $('.change-img').css({
    "background-image": "url('https://www.ryanhomes.com/rh-community-gallery-NewAspectRatio/7ac519ed-9b29-47b0-a489-ded2da8b770f/db/7ac519ed-9b29-47b0-a489-ded2da8b770f.jpg')"
  });
});
$('#services').hover(function() {
  $('.change-img').css({
    "background-image": "url('https://www.starwebcreations.com/new_images/services.jpg')"
  });
});
$('#portfolio').hover(function() {
  $('.change-img').css({
    "background-image": "url('https://www.ryanhomes.com/rh-community-gallery-NewAspectRatio/7ac519ed-9b29-47b0-a489-ded2da8b770f/db/7ac519ed-9b29-47b0-a489-ded2da8b770f.jpg')"
  });
});
$('#clients').hover(function() {
  $('.change-img').css({
    "background-image": "url('https://www.starwebcreations.com/new_images/services.jpg')"
  });
});
$('#contact').hover(function() {
  $('.change-img').css({
    "background-image": "url('https://www.ryanhomes.com/rh-community-gallery-NewAspectRatio/7ac519ed-9b29-47b0-a489-ded2da8b770f/db/7ac519ed-9b29-47b0-a489-ded2da8b770f.jpg')"
  });
});
```

```css
.side-bar {
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.side-bar>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.side-bar>ul>li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-sec {
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.change-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <ul>
      <li id="home">Home</li>
      <li id="services">Services</li>
      <li id="portfolio">Portfolio</li>
      <li id="clients">Clients</li>
      <li id="contact">Contacts</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="img-sec">
    <div class="change-img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work...the menu covers everything. And, it shows up on page load